# Translations on an affine straight line are projective transformations of the projective extension

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

> How do I prove that translations on an affine straight line are induced by projective transformations of the projective extension?

I know that a projective transformation is a projective map of a projective space to itself, but further I have no clue where to begin with this.

Edit: I don't think user @TheTriforce wants necessarily a reference, as much as he just would like an answer. (As would I :D )

Comment: @TheTriforce Could you maybe change your bounty reason to "drawing attention", as I think that is what you meant.

Comment: What context are we in here? Algebraic geometry? Synthetic projective geometry?

Comment: @SebastianConybeare Projective geometry

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701756/all-translations-on-mathbbr-are-induced-by-a-2-times2-matrix).It is even asked by the same person.